# How to chain view controller navigations (NSNotification not being received)

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, nsnotificationcenter

I have a custom in app notification appear at the top of any view controller on the screen when certain things happen.

Tapping on it triggers a notification:

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DidTapOnNotification" object:nil];`

The observer for that specific notification is the root navigation controller for my application, which I subclassed. I addObserver in `viewDidLoad`. This notification is always received, and the code I run in response is:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{ // this is called when the popToRootViewController animation completes
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2.0f * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NavigateToController" object:nil userInfo:notification.userInfo];
    });
}];

[self popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

[CATransaction commit];
```

I added a delay (dispatch_after) arbitrarily to see whether I just had to give my root view controller time to appear (i confirmed that it appeared before the 2 seconds are up).

Now, in my root view controller I again, add it as an observer for the `NavigateToGroup` notification. I.e. I call `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(openController:) name:@"NavigateToController" object:nil];` in `viewDidLoad`.

The problem is that the selector (i.e. the `openController:` method) is not always called. The only time it's called is when I'm already on that controller (the root controller) when I tap on the in app notification, then it works as expected. If I have other controllers on the navigation stack, tapping will popToRoot as expected, but then the method `openController:` will never get called even though I'm sure the notification gets posted (and i'm sure the view is appeared when it does).

Does anyone know what's going on here?
Or conversely, can anyone recommend a better way of handling this?

Comment: try to comment the  dispatch_after method and run. directly run the notification method. that view is disappered so we are not able to call the notification center.

Comment: That's what I was doing before, and similarly I have an NSLog statement just above the NSNotification call which does get printed to console. Is this a general thing or specific to NSNotificationCenter? (wondering bc the print statement gets logged). That maybe would make sense though, because the popToRoot wouldn't actually disappear the controller if I'm on the root, which is why that works. How would I get around this if that's the case (and do you know if that's the case for sure?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out HariKrishnan.P's comment had some truth to it. NSNotifications don't seem to be posted if the view controller that is sending the message has already been popped. (Not sure if this is always the case but definitely seemed to be the case here)

I ended up refactoring the code to only send one initial notification then bypassing this by using delegation and calling my method explicitly through it rather then relying on on an NSNotification, which is probably a better solution anyways.